# How to detect whether my Java application is active?

Tags: java, swing

I want to pause my game (written in Java Swing), when the player switches to another application.

But I did not find a way to detect this switch. `window.isActive()` only works for multiple windows within one Java application. But it does return `true`, when a different application has the focus.

The same is true for the `KeyboardFocusManager`, it returns the window of my application that had the focus before the focus was given to another application.

Comment: While you may be making a game, this issue is not solely related to game development. "*General programming questions more likely belong on Stack Overflow instead of here. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself... 
**Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?***" I think this question fails that test.

Answer (score 2):

Use the focus subsystem, as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

An example of detecting focus being gained:

```
//Make textField get the focus whenever frame is activated.
frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```